# how to respond to a post while writing to a file in java?

Tags: javascript, java, jquery

To Be precise I've a simple project where users can upload files to a server. So currently I need to show the user what is their connection upload speed to server. Based on research I had I Found one way of doing it is to check timing and amount of data received in server, which can give me an idea of what is the upload speed. The Thing I need to know is can I send a response to client while receiving the data stream and how?

Front-End Script:

```
var xhr=new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (xhr.readyState == XMLHttpRequest.DONE) {
       console.log(xhr.responseText);
    }
}
xhr.open('post','../uploadtostack',true);
xhr.setRequestHeader('X-File-Name',file.name);
xhr.setRequestHeader('x-File-Size',file.size);
xhr.setRequestHeader('X-File-Type',file.type);
xhr.send(file);
```

Back-End Script:

```
filecontent = request.getInputStream();
byte[] bytes = new byte[1024];
int read = 0;
while((read = filecontent.read(bytes))!=-1){
    out.print("wrote: "+read+" Bytes");
    output.write(bytes,0,read);
}
output.close();
```

As you can see in my back-end i'm respond with a simple value just to figure out is front-end receiving the data. But no luck I can't see no response in my front-end.

If you think There is a better solution to figure out upload speed. Thanks for sharing it.

Regards :)

Comment: @xufox6 don't worry I won't, But I was wondering why did the guy said to do it so. I mean It is pretty much required to my question. anyway do you know a solution to my problem?